# Regex for The Same Pattern Multiple Times in One Line

Tags: regex, sed

The pattern I'm looking for is this:

```
TXT.*\.txt
```

That pattern can occur multiple times in any given line. I would like to either extract each instance of the pattern out or alternatively delete the text that surrounds each instance using sed (or anything, really).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grep as:

```
grep -o 'TXT[^.]*\.txt' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Perl as:

```
$ cat file
foo TXT1.txt bar TXT2.txt baz
foo TXT3.txt bar TXT4.txt baz

$ perl -ne 'print "$1\n" while(/(TXT.*?\.txt)/g)' file
TXT1.txt
TXT2.txt
TXT3.txt
TXT4.txt
$
```