# How to find working regex pattern multiple times in single line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I want to validate an text input field with javascript regex validation.
Validation that is needed is: Input field should have one or multiple email ids, all ending with semicolon(;).

Thus, correct input would be :
→ user1@xxx.com;
→ user1@xxx.com;user2@xxx.com;
→ user1@xxx.com;user2@xxx.com;user3@xxx.com;

Incorrect input would be
→ user1@xxx.com                            -------- *Semicolon is missing*
→ user1@xxx                                    -------- *Email Id is invalid*
→ user1@xxx.com;user2@xxx.com -------- *Semicolon(;) is missing after second email id*

This is what I have tried so far which validates only one occurence of regex pattern, but not all occurences in single line.

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+(;)+$)
```

Regex URL: https://regex101.com/r/4svUQz/2/ 
[All 4 values in TEST STRING should match, but it is matching only first 2]
Also, I have checked below articles, but could not find answer.
[Regex single-line multiple match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455457/regex-single-line-multiple-match)
[Regex for The Same Pattern Multiple Times in One Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341309/regex-for-the-same-pattern-multiple-times-in-one-line)
[How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe this help you /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.com;)+$/.test('user1@xxx.com;user2@xxx.com;');

Answer (score 1):

First, for a simpler email regex to understand the principles involved, see [How to check for a valid email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/how-to-check-for-valid-email-address). I will use: `[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+` with the recommendation that we also exclude space characters and so, in your particular case requiring a semicolon at the end and allowing multiple email addresses on the line:

```
^([^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s.]+;)+$
```

Note that I took the basic regex for an email address and appended `;` and then put parentheses `()` around the entire expression and appended `+` signifying one or more times.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxjqBE/1/)

**Using your regex, with a slight simplification involving the `;` (i.e. removing unnecessary parentheses surrounding it):**

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)+;)+$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/trLDEr/2/)